# Get sid of the connection directly from the socketio server?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, fastapi, python-socketio

I'm using `python-socketio` for the server to communicate through websockets with clients (client apps use socketIO js client library).

From the docs, we can handle an event the following way:

```py
@sio.event
def my_event(sid, data):
    # handle the message
    return "OK", 123
```

How can I get the `sid` of the connection directly from the server? Without having to pass it as an arg as first argument from the js clients on each emitted events?
Websockets being bidirectional type of communication, there must be a better way,  `socket.io` server library for nodejs do provide such thing if I'm not wrong through a `socket.id` attribute both on the client part or the server one.

PS: I don't use `Flask-socketio` package, so I can't retrieve it via `request.sid`.
PS2: the socket server would be hosted on `uvicorn`, along with an `FastAPI` app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sid` is passed as the first argument in every call to an event handler. Examples:

```py
@sio.event
def my_event(sid, data):
    pass

@sio.on('my custom event')
def another_event(sid, data):
    pass
```

Documentation: https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#defining-event-handlers.

Comment: yes indeed, sorry about this, just realised i got misleaded as I was also passing a `token` payload to most of my events, thought I wasn't catching the `sid` but it did indeed the `sid`

Comment: Hey bro can I see your code